# Browser window going behind everything else when running selenium webdriver java scripts

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've an issue with my IE browser when running selenium WebDriver java scripts. For a while it will run in front of the screen, at some point of time it's going behind the screen and what ever other windows opened in the system comes to front. This is affecting the flow of the scripts run mostly. Can any one suggest a solution. Thanks !!!

Comment: This isn't a global problem. It doesn't happen for every web page or every JavaScript execution. We'll need some other information before being able to answer this. In particular, what are you trying to do in JavaScript, are you doing other operations like calling .clear() on an element, and what versions of WebDriver and the IEDriverServer.exe are you using?

Comment: I'm using Selenium-Java WebDriver, version 2.25.0. I initialized my driver in this way 'WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();'. And Yes of-course, this issue not happening in all my application pages. Once it hides behind all other windows, I bring it forward by clicking on browser again. When comes to some other page it goes hide in the same way as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue to some extend by using window.focus() method. Where ever IE window goes behind the screen, we must use it to bring it back infront of the screen. Here's the code snippet `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.focus()");`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There was a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2353) with the IE window being pushed to the bottom of the Z-order (to the background) when doing certain operations with the IE driver. Among these were calling `WebElement.click()` and selecting elements in a `<select>` element. These issues were corrected in [2.26.0.9](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/cpp/IEDriverServer/CHANGELOG) of the IEDriverServer.exe. Updating both your language bindings and your IEDriverServer.exe to the [latest version](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) (2.28, at the time of this writing) will likely solve your issue.